# How to use AJAX and jQuery with Sinatra route?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I want to send data from a form to a route in Sinatra, as in the following:

```
 <form action="/yelp/api" method="post" class="ajaxform">
          <input type="text" name="yelp_location" placeholder="Yelp Location">
          <input type="text" name="yelp_term" placeholder="Search Term">
          <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

And in the route, use this input to make a call to the Yelp API:

```
post '/yelp/api' do
  content_type :json
  @term = params[:yelp_term]
  @location = params[:yelp_location]

  # yelp search params
  params = { term: @term,
       limit: 20
     }

  locale = { lang: 'en' }
  client.search(@location, params, locale).to_json

end
```

I don't want a page refresh, so I'd like to do this using AJAX and jQuery. Is it possible to do this with Sinatra routes and AJAX? I've looked for examples, but they all seem to use PHP.

Edit: To be more specific, how would I go about grabbing from a route using AJAX? Examples are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this will work. What is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: @Brennan Figuring out how to actually use AJAX to grab the JSON response from the route.

Comment: Something like: `$.post('/yelp/api', params, function(response) { myData = response  })`